# How to lazy load nodes when expanded in jsTree?

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading, jstree

I have this js code to create a tree with the jsTree plugin.

```
    var n2 = {
          id          : "B", // will be autogenerated if omitted
          text        : "B", // node text
          icon        : undefined, // string for custom
          state       : {
            opened    : false,  // is the node open
            disabled  : false,  // is the node disabled
            selected  : false  // is the node selected
          },
          children    : [],  // array of strings or objects
          li_attr     : {},  // attributes for the generated LI node
          a_attr      : {},  // attributes for the generated A node 
        };
    var n1 = {
          id          : "A", // will be autogenerated if omitted
          text        : "A", // node text
          icon        : undefined, // string for custom
          state       : {
            opened    : false,  // is the node open
            disabled  : false,  // is the node disabled
            selected  : false  // is the node selected
          },
          children    : [n2],  // array of strings or objects
          li_attr     : {},  // attributes for the generated LI node
          a_attr      : {}  // attributes for the generated A node
        };


    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({ 
        'core' : {
            'data' : function (obj, cb) {
                console.log(obj);
                cb.call(this, [n1]);
            }
        }
    });
```

There is 2 nodes, A and B. B is a child of A. I want to set it so that B is a child of A, but B is only added to the DOM, when A is expanded the first time.

The above code doesn't work, it seems to always load B when A is loaded. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: From my interpretation of the documentation you can outline a node as `unloaded` which then using a jQuery event set to `load` or on a node `load_all` to load all of the children nodes.

Comment: Also based on the structure is it not possible to push new children into the children property on the object? Might require another method called refresh or something..

Comment: here we go https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/ under using ajax it explains how to use a core config and load items directly from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You just set `children` to true, which means it has children but it doesn't know them yet. The actual children can be stored in the `data` property. When the node is expanded, you just get the children from the `data` and return that, to render into the DOM. The data callback gets called on the initial load, and the id will be `#`, which means you need to return the root elements array. If it's not that, then you expanded a node.

```
    var n2 = {
          id          : "B", // will be autogenerated if omitted
          text        : "B", // node text
          icon        : undefined, // string for custom
          state       : {
            opened    : false,  // is the node open
            disabled  : false,  // is the node disabled
            selected  : false  // is the node selected
          },
          children    : [],  // array of strings or objects
          li_attr     : {},  // attributes for the generated LI node
          a_attr      : {},  // attributes for the generated A node 
        };
    var n1 = {
          id          : "A", // will be autogenerated if omitted
          text        : "A", // node text
          icon        : undefined, // string for custom
          state       : {
            opened    : false,  // is the node open
            disabled  : false,  // is the node disabled
            selected  : false  // is the node selected
          },
          children    : true,  // array of strings or objects
          data : [n2],
          li_attr     : {},  // attributes for the generated LI node
          a_attr      : {}  // attributes for the generated A node
        };
    var root = [n1];

    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({ 
        'core' : {
            'data' : function (obj, cb) {
                cb.call(this, obj.id == "#" ? root : obj.data);  
            }
        }
    });
```